# Find and count the number of elements of one DataFrame from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have 2 input dataFrames.

1. DatFrame one :

| a1 | a2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | C |
| B | D |
| F | D |
| A | D |

2. DatFrame two :

| emi_1 | emi_2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | C |
| B | L |
| C | N |
| G | D |

Output I want :
i want to count the number of occurrences of each element from df2 in df1 :
The expected output is show in this picture :
[image]

Note : It will be reader friendly if you group final dataframe according to IMEI so all Values of that particular will be grouped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way, step by step

```
>>> df1

  a1 a2
0  A  C
1  B  D
2  F  D
3  A  D

>>> df2

  emi_1 emi_2
0     A     C
1     B     L
2     C     N
3     G     D

>>> df2_melted = df2.melt(var_name="IMEI", value_name="Values")
>>> df2_melted

    IMEI Values
0  emi_1      A
1  emi_1      B
2  emi_1      C
3  emi_1      G
4  emi_2      C
5  emi_2      L
6  emi_2      N
7  emi_2      D

>>> df1_counts = df1.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
>>> df1_counts

    a1   a2
A  2.0  NaN
B  1.0  NaN
C  NaN  1.0
D  NaN  3.0
F  1.0  NaN

>>> final = (
         df2_melted.merge(df1_counts, how="left", 
                          left_on="Values", right_index=True)
                   .fillna(0)
                   .astype({"a1":int, "a2":int})
    )

>>> final

    IMEI Values  a1  a2
0  emi_1      A   2   0
1  emi_1      B   1   0
2  emi_1      C   0   1
3  emi_1      G   0   0
4  emi_2      C   0   1
5  emi_2      L   0   0
6  emi_2      N   0   0
7  emi_2      D   0   3
```

Comment: This particular example is for small data.Will this method be reliable on large data like 20,000 to 300000 rows?

Comment: The best way to find out is to test it yourself. But most likely yes, that is not much for pandas to handle.  The only non-vectorized method used is `apply`, which is not a big deal if `df1` doesn't have many columns.

Comment: @ZulqarnainSabir definitely much faster than the accepted solution.

Comment: I am testing it .I have large number of columns in df1 like 20-30 and each column could have upto 30k rows while df2 has very limited rows like 5-10

Comment: Your method is faster and working good so far